# Why does delete operator causes Debug Assertion Fail in Debug Mode?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, directx-9

Recently I noticed that my Engine is absolutely unoptimized so i decide to do a little cleanup. After implementing some of the culling algorithms I open Windows task manager to see how much my application uses memory. In result of my short research about "new" and "delete" operators I tried to use them for more efficiently memory usage.
For example:

```
void DrawSkybox()
{
p_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_FALSE );
D3DXVECTOR3* Scal = new D3DXVECTOR3(1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f);
D3DXVECTOR3* Rot = new D3DXVECTOR3(0, 0, 0);
obj_Skybox->Transform(&vec3_camera_viewPos, Scal, Rot);
DrawObject(p_Device, obj_Skybox, NULL, NULL, NULL, false);
p_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_TRUE );
delete Scal;
delete Rot;
}
```

In the first time I compiled and executed debug version of Engine I received an error: "Debug Assertion Failed". Then I compiled and executed my Engine as a Release - everything is just fine. So what is the problem?

Comment: Why don't you just create those instances on the stack like `D3DXVECTOR3 Scal(1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f);`? I don't see any need for using `new`/`delete`here at all.`

Comment: Probably because you do something bad with the memory, like writing out of bounds or something else that probably leads to [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)?

Comment: If you are already refactoring your C++ code, why not switch to using modern RAII style memory management?  You'll be surprised how many problems will simply *go away*.

Comment: And have you tried running in a debugger, to see that the problem really is where you think it is?

Comment: @Ocelot Of course the memory of stack instantiated variables will be freed automatically as soon the scope is left. That's all of the point about this RAII thing.

Comment: A release build does not contain any assertions. So you won't get any, even if you are trashing memory.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You mean that in D3DXVECTOR3 class already have RAII functionality?

Comment: @Ocelot Since they're [just simple PODs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I'd suspect so, yes. As mentioned, no need for `new/delete`, if you need to pass them as pointers to functions somewhere, just take the address of that stack variable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But what to do if i call method this way:
effect->SetVector("windDirForce", new D3DXVECTOR4(windDirForce.x, windDirForce.y, windDirForce.z, windDirForce.w));

Comment: @Ocelot _"But what to do if i call ..."_ As mentioned before, you create a variable and pass its address: `D3DXVECTOR4 tmp(windDirForce.x, windDirForce.y, windDirForce.z, windDirForce.w); effect->SetVector("windDirForce", &tmp);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then may you give me advice about where I can use "new" operator and where it's necessary to use it? Following the discussion I started to think that this operator is useless and may cause a lot of garbage in memory.

Comment: @Ocelot See [here for example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205729(v=vs.85).aspx), the reference doesn't say anything, that you'll need to create the `pVector` parameter on the heap. _"and where it's necessary to use it?"_ Usually it isn't necessary. But there are use cases for it, but far beyond your concerns in this context.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Your method `D3DXVECTOR4 tmp(windDirForce.x, windDirForce.y, windDirForce.z, windDirForce.w); effect->SetVector("windDirForce", &tmp);` doesn't compile. The compilation output is something like "Unable to convert parameter 2 from "D3DXVECTOR4" to "const D3DXVECTOR4 *" "(I have Russian VC++ so I'm not sure about how exactly error message looks like in English)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, that was my fault, everything work fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Ocelot: `new` is for when you need a variable to continue to exist well after the function exits, or when you need to have a dynamic-sized array.  There's very very few other uses for it.

Comment: If you are familiar with XNA Game Studio, you might want to take a look at using [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) for Direct3D 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better should refactor your code in this way, instead of bothering about `new` and `delete`:

```
void DrawSkybox() {
     p_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_FALSE );
     D3DXVECTOR3 Scal(1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f); // <<<< Just use stack 
     D3DXVECTOR3 Rot (0, 0, 0);          // <<<< allocated variables ...
     obj_Skybox->Transform(&vec3_camera_viewPos, &Scal, &Rot); // <<< ... and pass 
                                                               // their addresses
     DrawObject(p_Device, obj_Skybox, NULL, NULL, NULL, false);
     p_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_TRUE );
}
```

I can't tell anymore details about that actual assertion failure you get, but it's occuring in debug mode only, and release mode compiled code won't notice what's going on.
The errors seem to stem from something different in your code elsewhere, but shouldn't from just introducing the `delete` statements.

Comment: Thanks, the result of replacing new operator by temporary variables reduces memory usage a lot! Also memory stops to increasing every second and right now work and allocates stable.

Comment: Your original code implies to me that you came from C# where that pattern is common. In C++, ``new`` is not as 'cheap' as it is in C# where there's no garbage collection. You should take some time to review a C++ book to understand the difference between 'automatic' variables on the stack, heap-allocated memory, and other aspects of the C++ memory model.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn You absolutely right about that, I came from C# in order to try out managed dx.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Ping the OP please, that's not done automatically from comments on answers.